# Is it possible to disable cascade delete for a specific Core Data save?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Question:

When you call save on `NSManagedObjectContext` when there are `deletedObjects` to be dealt with, it does a good deal of work tracking down the relationships to determine which related objects also need to be deleted.  This is done with every save (even in the case of parent / child contexts), if I know I'll be saving right through those parent contexts, I would like to be able to skip this check for every context after the first, however I can't find the mechanism to do so.

Background:

Here is the situation, I have 3 contexts:

- C (Child context of B): A background thread context for doing work
- B (Child context of A): A Main thread context, for my Fetch Result Controllers, UI access
- A (Child of Persistent Store): A background thread context for saving to disk

My object graph is "Rich" and some of the relationships are against tables that have 100,000+ items.  Because of this, deletions are understandably slow (Cascade delete removes a number of objects with each root object deletion)...  However when analyzing the performance I realized it's actually A LOT slower than it needs to be, during a save a majority of the CPU / time is used in resolving the relationships in the graph (To try and figure out which related objects also need to be deleted)...  And it repeats this process EVERY save, even though I'm saving right through.
Example save process:

- Context C has 1 deleted object
- Save Context C -> B (around 1 second of work is being done tracking down the relationships)
- Context C now saved (0 deleted objects), Context B has the original deleted object, and 30 new related objects that also needed to be deleted (31 Objects)
- Save Context B -> A (Around 1 second of work *rechecking* those relationships, this is the work I'd like to skip)
- Context B Saved (0 deleted objects), Context A has the same 31 objects that B had to delete
- Save Context A -> Persistent Store (Light work here, seems that this step doesn't bother with a recheck)

I tried subclassing and looking into `-[NSManagedObject validateForDeletion]` and `-[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges]` with no luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought, could be completely wrong. Have you tried emptying the context you don't want doing any work i.e. `reset`. Of course that would only be OK if you didn't need to save any changes that that particular context has accrued.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to selectively enable/disable a delete rule **if you use multiple Core Data stacks** and if you don't mind getting into some moderately complex code. You'll end up with multiple managed object contexts where some have the rule and some don't. The deal is:

- An `NSManagedObjectModel` is mutable when you first load it, so you can modify the model in code as long as you don't make changes that would make it incompatible with your persistent store (which would require migration).
- Model compatibility is determined only by details that affect how data is saved to the persistent store. **Delete rules are not included**, so they can be modified without requiring migration. (see the documentation for `[NSRelationshipDescription versionHash]` for what does affect compatibility.
- Instances of `NSManagedObjectModel` are only mutable **until you use them with a persistent store**, so you have to make your changes before loading any data. This means that if you want the delete rule in some cases but not in others, you need different instances of `NSManagedObjectModel`.

So, if you create entirely independent Core Data stacks (separate instances of `NSManagedObjectModel`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, etc, everything) you could configure one stack to not have these delete rules but leave them in place on others. Since delete rules don't affect the model hash, they'd still be compatible.

You cannot do this with parent/child managed object contexts, since they by definition are part of the same Core Data stack.

To remove or change the delete rule, you'll have to start with your instance of `NSManagedObjectModel`. Get the `entities` in the model, then get `relationshipsByName` for the entity you're interested in. Finally, on the `NSRelationshipDescription`, change `deleteRule` to whatever you want (probably `NullifyDeleteRule` in this case).

This is going to be kind of complicated but it should work.

As an aside, I'd be interested in knowing more detail about what your performance analysis showed.

Comment: Hmm... Not sure if this works for my scenario, as the goal here is to be able to save through the parent / child contexts without incurring additional relationship lookup overhead.  Kind of neat idea though, if I could tamper with the model for a specific managed object context it might work...  As a second potential gotcha however, I think NullifyDeleteRule would still perform a relationship lookup (at least in many-many) so that it could nullify (or delete) the relationship row :(  Might be a little faster, but I want to skip the check altogether.

Comment: Changing the delete rule for a particular context doesn't work when they're in the same stack, since you have to make the change at the model level. A different approach that might work is use `NSNoActionDeleteRule` but override `prepareForDeletion` to handle the cascade effect yourself.

Comment: This most recent comment should be your answer.  Setting it to NSNoActionDeleteRule and then managing the delete yourself in prepareForDeletion would indeed allow for choosing when and how often the delete calculation occurs. -- In regards to your questions on performance, in our case we are using a custom SQL backed NSIncrementalStore -- 70% of the CPU involved in a deletion is tied up in "newFetchToManyRelationship" mostly because one of the tables in the relationship has a large number of records.